# Margin getting added before div (visually)

Tags: css, margin

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7KxtZ/

I have the following CSS, and I don't know why my margin looks like is getting added to the div. I know it is getting added to the `h1`, but it looks like it is the div why do browsers do that? In the JSFiddle, you can see the gray space above the div. How can I remove it without creating a margin, because the same thing happens with `ul` and other elements with a top margin?

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #e8ebef;
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#body{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

from `html, body` to `*`

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7KxtZ/1/

Comment: Works, but that just removes margin from everything.

Comment: @ryan naddy You can also set it to the h1, but this is just a general reset

Comment: @RyanNaddy see this fiddle, be sure to remove it from the body and h1 http://jsfiddle.net/7KxtZ/2/

Comment: I got it! I added padding to `.wrapper`